# Hide button until button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide the id="Watch" button.
until the class="button1" button is clicked
The countdown ends
Then the id="Watch" button appears.

```js
function DelayRedirect() {
    var seconds = 10;
    var dvCountDown = document.getElementById("dvCountDown");
    var lblCount = document.getElementById("lblCount");
    dvCountDown.style.display = "block";
    lblCount.innerHTML = seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        lblCount.innerHTML = seconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            dvCountDown.style.display = "none";
            window.location = "#Watch";
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
    <button class="button1" onclick="DelayRedirect()">continue</button>
    
    <div id="dvCountDown" style = "display:none">
You will be redirected after <span id = "lblCount"></span>&nbsp;seconds.
</div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <button id="Watch"><a class="button2" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Watch</i></a></button>
```

Comment: Wrapping a a tag inside a button doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your HTML code is 'illegal'. Put it through a validator and edit your question so that the structure makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

just set opacity 0 on #Watch and when button1 is clicked set opacity = 1 on #Watch. After the countdown reset #Watch opacity to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

Adding display to `none` in `HTML` by default,

`<button style="display : none" id="Watch"><a class="button2" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Watch</i></a></button>`

After this grab the button and set `display` to `block` once you click the `button`.

```js
let one = document.querySelector(".button1");
let second = document.querySelector("#Watch");
one.addEventListener("click" , DelayRedirect);
function DelayRedirect() {
  second.style.display = "block";
  var seconds = 10;
  var dvCountDown = document.getElementById("dvCountDown");
  var lblCount = document.getElementById("lblCount");
  dvCountDown.style.display = "block";
  lblCount.innerHTML = seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
      seconds--;
      lblCount.innerHTML = seconds;
      if (seconds === 0) {
          dvCountDown.style.display = "none";
          window.location = "#Watch";
      }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>My Website</title>
    <!-- <script src="./src/index.js" defer ></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button1" >continue</button>
    
    <div id="dvCountDown" style = "display:none">
You will be redirected after <span id = "lblCount"></span>&nbsp;seconds.
</div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <button style="display : none" id="Watch"><a class="button2" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Watch</i></a></button>
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
    <!-- added defer also -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it `display: none` by default, and after ten seconds give it `display: inline`, also you should stop the `interval` as it will run forever.

```js
function DelayRedirect() {
    var seconds = 10;
    var dvCountDown = document.getElementById("dvCountDown");
    var lblCount = document.getElementById("lblCount");
    dvCountDown.style.display = "block";
    lblCount.innerHTML = seconds;
    const timeout = setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        lblCount.innerHTML = seconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            dvCountDown.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('Watch').style.display = 'inline';
            window.location = "#Watch";
            clearInterval(timeout)
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#Watch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button1" onclick="DelayRedirect()">continue</button>
    
    <div id="dvCountDown" style = "display:none">
You will be redirected after <span id = "lblCount"></span>&nbsp;seconds.
</div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <button id="Watch"><a class="button2" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Watch</i></a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### This can be solved by using the *hidden* attribute on the button

**For The Html**

```html
<button class="button1">continue</button>
    
    <div id="dvCountDown" style = "display:none">
You will be redirected after <span id = "lblCount"></span>&nbsp;seconds.
</div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<!--I would recommend using CSS to position your elements instead of <br> tags-->

    <button id="Watch" hidden><a class="button2" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Watch</i></a></button>
```

**The Javascript Portion is**

```js
const watchButton = document.getElementById('Watch');
const button1 = document.getElementByClassName('button1');

watchButton.addEventListener('click', delayRedirect() {
    watchButton.removeAttribute('hidden');
    watchButton.setTimeout(() => {
           watchButton.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
     }
,10000)

})
```

Comment: Would have voted this up for the use of `hidden`, but there's at least four errors that prevent the code from running.